# How to return value from empty function in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have the following code:

```
function done(err, file) {

  //handle code

  return "test";
}

function process() {

    retext()
     .use(keywords)
     .process(sentence, done);
  

    return val; 
}
```

The `process()` function **must** return the value of `retext()`, but the `retext()` function doesn't seem to return anything.

If I change it to:

```
const val = retext()
     .use(keywords)
     .process(sentence, done);
```

That still doesn't work

How can I get `retext()` to return something. It is just an NPM package I installed

I tried returning `test` in the `done()` function but that doesn't pass anything to return to `retext()`.

I have also tried:

```
retext()
      .use(keywords)
      .process(params.t, done).then((val) => return val);
```

**To summarise**:

`process()` must return the value of `done()`, which is called by `retext()`

Comment: `retext` _does_ return something, otherwise this chaining would be impossible. But `process` probably doesn't return anything.

Comment: I want to get the value of `retext()`, how do I do that?

Comment: `const result = retext(); result.use(keywords).process(sentence, done); return result;` But I _really_ doubt that's what you meant.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log`ging what this actually returns?

Comment: @tkausl That seems close to what I meant, in your example, I just need `return result` to return something. The `done()` function returns a string and works correctly, but I just need to store that value from that function in `result` called from `retext()`

Comment: Oh, _now_ I got it. Alright, so what you're trying to do is not possible. Your function will return _before_ done is even called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @tkausl `return result` in your example just returns the `retext()` function itself, and ignores the `.process(sentence, done);` value

Comment: @tkausl Nope unfortunately,

Answer (score 0):

*Update:
Looks like I completely missed the context around this question. But for posterity, the OP, [@ewfewfjio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19510642/ewfewfjio), figured out a workaround in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73102193/how-to-return-value-from-empty-function-in-node#comment129110027_73102321) to use global variables instead.

---

I am not familiar with the `retext` package. However from the documentations available [here](https://unifiedjs.com/explore/package/retext/#use), the `retext` function looks like it's asynchronous. As such you will need to `await` the result. You will also need to convert the `process` into an async function. However, without a reproducible/working problem, it's difficult to suggest solutions.

If I am missing something, please share a fiddle or some code snippet we can replicate.

```js
async function process() {
  const val = await retext()
    .use(keywords)
    .process(sentence, done);
  console.log(val); // should work now
  return val;
}
```

Additionally when you are calling the `process` function, you'll need to `await` again.

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/async-await-function-in-javascript/) is a very nice tutorial on `async/await` in javascript.

Comment: This would only work if `process` returns a Promise. Given that OP passes a callback to it I guess it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, probably not. I did not see the comments under the original post when I posted. I presumed it was an async await issue when I saw `retext` was async

Comment: @tkausl This didn't work but I found a workaround where I just use global variables, set the global variables in `done()`

Comment: @ewfewfjio just for posterity, what are `keywords` and `sentence` are they a list of strings?

Any way we can recreate the issue? Just in case someone else stumbles across this thread.

Comment: @dotdeb `keywords` is just an NPM package I got from doing `const keywords = require('retext-keywords');` `Sentence` is just any string, it will take it and extract the keywords